# Img attr src will not change

Tags: jquery, src, attr

Heres the situation i am able to show on hover the src as being chenged but the image on the screen itself doesnt actualy change. any help would be a great help.

```
$('.hoverImgs').hover(
function(){mouseOn = 1; formSelector('hover');},
function(){mouseOn = 0; formSelector('out');
});

function formSelector(method){
if(mouseOn === 1 && method === 'hover'){       
    $(this).attr("src", "images/radio_hover.png");
    alert($(this).attr("src"));
}
else {}
}
});
```

Comment: `this` doesn't have any jQuery context in your function.. it is the window

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The context is lost when you call the function `formSelector` and `this` would window object inside the function. You should either pass `this` object as an argument or invoke the function using `.call/.apply`.

Try like below,

```
$(function () {
   var mouseOn;
   $('.hoverImgs').hover(
      function(){ mouseOn = 1; formSelector('hover', this); },
      function(){mouseOn = 0; formSelector('out', this); }
   );

  function formSelector(method, thisObj){
     if(mouseOn === 1 && method === 'hover'){       
       thisObj.src = "images/radio_hover.png";
       alert(thisObj.src);
     }
     else {}
   }

});
```

Answer (score 2):

First, you have an extra `});` at the end.

Your real problem: `this` is not what you think it is. In that context, `this` refers to the window object, not the image. One way to fix that is pass in the image element into the functions.

```
$('.hoverImgs').hover(
  function(){mouseOn = 1; formSelector($(this), 'hover');},
  function(){mouseOn = 0; formSelector($(this), 'out');}
);

function formSelector(elem, method){
  if(mouseOn === 1 && method === 'hover'){
    console.log(elem.attr('src'));
    elem.attr("src", "https://www.google.com/images/srpr/logo3w.png");
  }
}
```

[Demo](http://jsbin.com/icexix/1)